# find the index of values that satisfy A + B =C + D

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Working on below problem, using Python 2.7. Post my code and wondering if any further smart ideas to make it run faster? I thought there might be some ideas which sort the list first, and leveraging sorting behavior, but cannot figure out so far. My code is `O(n^2)` time complexity.

**Problem**,

Given an array A of integers, find the index of values that satisfy A + B =C + D, where A,B,C & D are integers values in the array. Find all combinations of quadruples.

**Code**,

```
from collections import defaultdict

sumIndex = defaultdict(list)

def buildIndex(numbers):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(numbers)):
            sumIndex[numbers[i]+numbers[j]].append((i,j))

def checkResult():
    for k,v in sumIndex.items():
        if len(v) > 1:
            for i in v:
                print k, i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buildIndex([1,2,3,4])
    checkResult()
```

**Output**, which is sum value, and indexes which sum could result in such value,

```
5 (0,3)
5 (1,2)
```

Comment: More suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com website.

Comment: You added wrong output. The actual output : `5 (0, 3)
5 (1, 2)
`

Comment: @GaneshMatkam, thanks for the correction. Updated.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, tried similar question before, they said code review is not for performance improvement discussion, just for coding style. :(

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where all the elements of the array are equal. Then we know the answer beforehand but merely printing the result will take `O(n^2)` time since there are `n*(n-1)/2` number of such pairs. So I think it is safe to say that there is no approach with a better complexity than `O(n^2)` for this problem.

Comment: Thanks sudomakeinstall2, vote up for your reply. Do you think there are any improvements (even if still O(n^2)) to do if we do sorting?

Comment: @LinMa If you wanted to find pairs with a specified sum there were some methods that could benefit from sorting and binary search but since you want to find all pairs with all possible sums I can't think of any improvements for your existing code.

Comment: Thanks sudomakeinstall2, any functional bugs in my code you are aware?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done in a way with complexity less than O(n^2). The algo is:

1. Create a duplicate array suppose indexArr[] storing the index of the element of the original array say origArr[].
2. Sort the origArr[] in ascending order using some algo having complexity O(nLogn). Likewise also shuffle the indexArr[] while sorting the origArr[].
3. Now you have to find the pairs in the sorted array, you will run 2 loops finding all the possible combinations. Suppose you select `origArr[i] + origArr[i + 1] = sum.`
4. Now you will search iff `sum <= origArr[n]` where n is the last element of the array which is the maximum element. Also if `sum > origArr[n]` then you will break the inner loop as well as the outer loop as no other combinations are possible.
5. Also you will break the inner loop if `sum > origArr[j]` as no other combinations are possible for that sum.

PS - The worst case scenario will be O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, and vote up for your reply, for your comments -- "find the pairs in the sorted array, you will run 2 loops finding all the possible combinations", I think you mean the same implementation in my code of i and j loops? Or some other implementation (e.g. you loop from begin, and the other inner loop from end)? If you could show your code, it will be great to clarify a lot.

Comment: And for your comments "Now you will search iff sum <= origArr[n]", I am not sure if it is safe to do this since sum is addition of two elements, and origArr[n] is max value of one element, it is definitely possible two elements' sum is greater than another element, if you mean `sum <= 2*origArr[n]`, I agree. Anyway, if you could show your code, it will be much clear. :)

Comment: Yes, it will be as your implementation but as i mentioned, the worst case scenario will be same as yours. Im just breaking my loop based on some conditions.
Consider the sorted array [7, 9, 11, 14 ]. Now max of the array is 14(n). So if you consider 7(i) + 9(i+1) = 15(sum). And as 15 > 14,  no combinations are possible. Point me out if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks kingshuk, but I do not think checking `numbers[i] + numners[i+1]` > max(numbers) helps. For example, suppose sorted array is [2,7,9,14], 7(i) + 9(i+1) = 15(sum). And as 15 > 14, but it is possible 2+14 == 7+9, so you miss an equal condition. If I mis-read any of your points, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Well I think we are thinking in a different way. For 2+14 == 7+9, will be covered before  7(i) + 9(i+1) = 15(sum). I mean as we have two loops, so when outer loop will point to 2, and inner loop will make combinations of (2,7), (2,9), (2,14). After that outer loop will point to 7 and you will make combinations of (7,9) and (7,14). So your query will be covered before the loop is exited.

Comment: Thanks kingshuk, so you check `numbers[i] + numbers[i+1] > sum` only in inner loop?

Comment: Thanks kingshuk, so you check `numbers[i] + numbers[i+1] > sum` only in inner loop? And in your example, when you outer/inner loop calculate combination (2,7), (2,9), you mean no need to calculate (2,14)?

Comment: Hi kingshuk, if you have a chance to comment on my above question, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 1):

faster, more Pythonic approach using `itertools.combinations:`

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

def get_combos(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for indices in combinations(range(len(l)),2):
        d[(l[indices[0]] + l[indices[1]])].append(indices)
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

---

*timing results*

```
                                             OP       this
len(l)=4, min(repeat=100, number=10000) | 0.09334  | 0.08050
len(l)=50, min(repeat=10, number=100)   | 0.08689  | 0.08996
len(l)=500, min(repeat=10, number=10)   | 0.64974  | 0.59553
len(l)=1000, min(repeat=3, number=3)    | 1.01559  | 0.83494
len(l)=5000, min(repeat=3, number=1)    | 10.26168 | 8.92959
```

---

*timing code*

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from random import randint
from timeit import repeat


def lin_get_combos(l):
    sumIndex = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
            sumIndex[l[i]+l[j]].append((i,j))
    return {k:v for k,v in sumIndex.items() if len(v) > 1}

def craig_get_combos(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for indices in combinations(range(len(l)),2):
        d[(l[indices[0]] + l[indices[1]])].append(indices)
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v) > 1}

l = []
for _ in range(4):
    l.append(randint(0,1000))
t1 = min(repeat(stmt='lin_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import lin_get_combos, l', repeat=100, number=10000))
t2 = min(repeat(stmt='craig_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import craig_get_combos, l', repeat= 100, number=10000))
print '%0.5f, %0.5f' % (t1, t2)

l = []
for _ in range(50):
    l.append(randint(0,1000))
t1 = min(repeat(stmt='lin_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import lin_get_combos, l', repeat=10, number=100))
t2 = min(repeat(stmt='craig_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import craig_get_combos, l', repeat= 10, number=100))
print '%0.5f, %0.5f' % (t1, t2)

l = []
for _ in range(500):
    l.append(randint(0,1000))
t1 = min(repeat(stmt='lin_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import lin_get_combos, l', repeat=10, number=10))
t2 = min(repeat(stmt='craig_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import craig_get_combos, l', repeat= 10, number=10))
print '%0.5f, %0.5f' % (t1, t2)

l = []
for _ in range(1000):
    l.append(randint(0,1000))
t1 = min(repeat(stmt='lin_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import lin_get_combos, l', repeat=3, number=3))
t2 = min(repeat(stmt='craig_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import craig_get_combos, l', repeat= 3, number=3))
print '%0.5f, %0.5f' % (t1, t2)

l = []
for _ in range(5000):
    l.append(randint(0,1000))
t1 = min(repeat(stmt='lin_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import lin_get_combos, l', repeat=3, number=1))
t2 = min(repeat(stmt='craig_get_combos(l)', setup='from __main__ import craig_get_combos, l', repeat= 3, number=1))
print '%0.5f, %0.5f' % (t1, t2)
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, your code is pretty cool. Do you think if there is a further way to improve by sorting?

Comment: BTW, I am thinking why your code is faster, is it majorly because of `itertools.combinations` is faster than writing a two nested loop?

Comment: @LinMa Yes, the only difference is that I use `itertools.combinations` to get the set of unique index pairs, whereas you use a nested `for loop` in the OP. In general it is better and faster to use Python libraries to `do x`, rather than writing our own Python code to `do x`, as the timing results demonstrate. As far as sorting goes, I would guess that there is no technique that could take advantage of sorting to show a significant speed improvement, except maybe in some edge cases. The reason is that we need to look at all sums, not just sums less than or greater than a certain value.

Comment: Thanks Craig, if you look at reply from Ganesh, it seems a lot performance improvement by sorting? How do you think?